# Unpivot the data with an incremental dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, unpivot

Hi I've the data in the below format [Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwzCM.png)

---

`+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Item | Channel | Location | STARTDATE | PERIOD1 | PERIOD2 | PERIOD3 | PERIOD4 |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A101 | Online  | NY       | 7/17/2017 | 1       |         | 1       |         |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A102 | Store   | PV       | 7/24/2017 | 1       |         | 1       | 1       |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+`

I want the period1 to be replaced by startdate+7 days,   period2 by startdate+14 days and so on, basically weekly bucket.

---

And the above data should look like this:
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQhxZ.png)

`+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| Item | Channel | Location | STARTDATE | Period    | QTY |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A101 | Online  | NY       | 7/17/2017 | 7/24/2017 | 1   |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A101 | Online  | NY       | 7/17/2017 | 7/31/2017 |     |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A101 | Online  | NY       | 7/17/2017 | 8/7/2017  | 1   |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A101 | Online  | NY       | 7/17/2017 | 8/14/2017 |     |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A102 | Store   | PV       | 7/24/2017 | 7/31/2017 | 1   |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A102 | Store   | PV       | 7/24/2017 | 8/7/2017  |     |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A102 | Store   | PV       | 7/24/2017 | 8/14/2017 | 1   |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| A102 | Store   | PV       | 7/24/2017 | 8/21/2017 | 1   |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----+`

Comment: Don't include screen captures of your data, include it directly in the question.  This is probably a duplicate in any case.

Comment: i tried for so long to put tables even after converting the text to table but it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Here are my create and insert statements for testing:

```
create table Testing
(
  ITEM varchar2(4),
  CHANNEL varchar2(10),
  LOCATION varchar2(2),
  STARTDATE date,
  PERIOD1 number,
  PERIOD2 number,
  PERIOD3 number,
  PERIOD4 number
  );

 insert into Testing
 values('A101','Online','NY',to_date('07/17/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'),1,cast(null as number),1,cast(null as number));
 insert into Testing
 values('A102','Store','PV',to_date('07/24/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'),1,cast(null as number),1,1);
```

After that, I was able to create this unpivot which gives you what you want as long as you don't care about the null quantity rows:

```
select ITEM "Item", CHANNEL "Channel", LOCATION "Location", STARTDATE "StartDate", 
        STARTDATE + 7 * to_number(substr(PERIOD,-1)) "Period", QTY
 from 
 Testing
 unpivot(
    QTY for Period in (period1,period2,period3,period4)
 )
```

Output for Query 1:

```
Item    Channel     Location    StartDate   Period      QTY
A101    Online      NY          17-JUL-17   24-JUL-17   1
A101    Online      NY          17-JUL-17   07-AUG-17   1
A102    Store       PV          24-JUL-17   31-JUL-17   1
A102    Store       PV          24-JUL-17   14-AUG-17   1
A102    Store       PV          24-JUL-17   21-AUG-17   1
```

If for some reason you needed those null rows, you can just put a NVL around each period before unpivoting:

```
select ITEM "Item", CHANNEL "Channel", LOCATION "Location", STARTDATE "StartDate", 
        STARTDATE + 7 * to_number(substr(PERIOD,-1)) "Period", QTY
 from(
 select ITEM,CHANNEL,LOCATION,STARTDATE,nvl(PERIOD1,0) PERIOD1,nvl(PERIOD2,0) PERIOD2,nvl(PERIOD3,0) PERIOD3,nvl(PERIOD4,0) PERIOD4
 from Testing
 )
 unpivot(
    QTY for Period in (period1,period2,period3,period4)
 )
```

Output for Query 2:

```
Item    Channel     Location    StartDate   Period      QTY
A101    Online      NY          17-JUL-17   24-JUL-17   1
A101    Online      NY          17-JUL-17   31-JUL-17   0
A101    Online      NY          17-JUL-17   07-AUG-17   1
A101    Online      NY          17-JUL-17   14-AUG-17   0
A102    Store       PV          24-JUL-17   31-JUL-17   1
A102    Store       PV          24-JUL-17   07-AUG-17   0
A102    Store       PV          24-JUL-17   14-AUG-17   1
A102    Store       PV          24-JUL-17   21-AUG-17   1
```

Answer (score 0):

`Connect By` Method with a `Cross Join` might be used as :

```
 with Inventory ( Item , Channel , Location , Startdate , Period1 , Period2 , Period3 , Period4 ) as
 (
   select 'A101', 'Online', 'NY', date'2017-07-17', 1, null, 1, null from dual union all
   select 'A102', 'Store' , 'PV', date'2017-07-24', 1, null, 1,    1 from dual   
 )
 select Item , Channel , Location , Startdate ,
        Startdate + 7 * lvl as Period,
        decode(lvl,1,period1,2,period2,3,period3,4,period4) as qty
   from Inventory i
   cross join ( select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 4 )
   order by item, lvl;

ITEM    CHANNEL LOCATION    STARTDATE     PERIOD     QTY
----    ------- --------   -----------  ----------   ----
A101    Online     NY      17.07.2017   24.07.2017    1
A101    Online     NY      17.07.2017   31.07.2017   NULL
A101    Online     NY      17.07.2017   07.08.2017    1
A101    Online     NY      17.07.2017   14.08.2017   NULL
A102    Store      PV      24.07.2017   31.07.2017    1
A102    Store      PV      24.07.2017   07.08.2017   NULL
A102    Store      PV      24.07.2017   14.08.2017    1
A102    Store      PV      24.07.2017   21.08.2017    1
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/BSII1803)